# How do I draw a EditText to canvas in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-canvas, ondraw

I would like to draw

```
EditText username = new EditText(context);
```

to a specific spot on my canvas in

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

}
```

Is it possible to draw it on the basis of `x,y` coordinate in my Java file without using XML layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can draw `EditText` on `Canvas`, Here is hint:

```
EditText ed;
.
.
.
.
.   
ed.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = ed.getDrawingCache();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, l, t, r, b, null);
```

You can create/initialize `EditText` at run time like this:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setText("My Text");
editText.setWidth(180);         
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: trying it out and my current issue is the ed.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); eclipse doesnt show any errors but program wont run on emulator. Is there a certain class I should place this command in? tried onDraw() { }, and public TitleView(Context context){  }

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "program wont run on emulator"??

Comment: and what do you mean when you say "my current issue is the ed.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);" ?

Comment: Emulator says "StudentConnect(name of my app) has stopped", when "ed.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);" is placed into my code.  Without it runs fine.  And I have initialized the EditText with EditText ed;

Comment: I guess you didn't understand that it was **hint**. Anyways I have added code to initialize it at runtime. Just make sure you are not creating instances in `onDraw()` method to avoid lots of gc.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate not just being handed the answer, will look around and experiment.

Comment: Sorry I am new to android unlike you

Comment: @M-WaJeEh May I know what am I supposed to do with these parameters: bitmap, l, t, r, b?

Answer (score -2):

You can't draw an EditText to canvas in Android.  That's not what Canvas is for.

What you can do is use a FrameLayout, put the Canvas inside of it, and put and EditText on top of the Canvas.

Comment: you cannot put Canvas inside FrameLayout, that's not what FrameLayout is for.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 - M-WaJeE4's not "draw[ing] an EditText to canvas" - he's scraping a bitmap *from* the EditText and *then* drawing that into the canvas. Shouldn't that work ?

Comment: @HowardPautz you may be right - perhaps I didn't read the question well enough :)